# Is the convolution algebra a *-algebra?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, convolution

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group with $n$ elements. Consider the convolution algebra $C^*(G) \subset l^2(G)$, with multiplication: $$(a * b )(g) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{x\in G} a(x)b(g-x)$$
Is there a certain involution map $\phi: C^*(G) \rightarrow C^*(G)$ such that $\phi(\phi(a))=a$ and $\phi(ab)=\phi(b)\phi(a)$  (Such that $C^*(G)$ is a $*$-algebra)?

Comment: To make things easier to read, you may want to replace some of the stars with another symbol.

Comment: Also, you seem to be writing the group additively, even though you have not assumed it to be abelian. Is this intentional?

Comment: I hope it is more clear the way I edited it.

Comment: Actually, isn't this algebra just the group algebra? If you define $f_g = n\delta_{x,g}$ then these satisfy $f_g * f_h = f_{g+h}$.

Comment: that is true I see, so an involution map $\phi$ can be given by $f_g \mapsto f_{g^-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly (and you don't need the group to be abelian for this).